# Kernel Panic : VFS :Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block

Tags: raspbian, boot, kernel

I was having an issue with my Pi, and ended up having to refresh my SD card with a new copy of Raspbian. I followed the links and instructions on the Raspberry Pi site about cleaning the SD card. I wiped the card and refreshed it and now I just get this error on the boot screen:

```
Kernel Panic: VFS : Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block (179,2)
```

I have reflashed the drive 3 or 4 times to no avail. If anyone can help that would be appreciated.

Comment: This likely means something is wrong with the image or SD card; have you followed the [instructions](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/) to write an image exactly? Do you have another SD card that you could try?

Comment: Please let me know if you don't have your question answered by the dupe.